# Input Output String function

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry to sound like a noob but how do I create an input / output function in Objective C for an iPhone app.

What I am trying to do is create a function where I pass it a string, the string get evaluated in the function then it returns back result in a string.

This is what I have done so far which of course is wrong as it doesn't compile.

in my *.h file

```
void my_func(NSString *string);
```

in my *.m file

```
void my_func(NSString *string)
{
    NSMutableString *statusBack;


    if ([string isEqualToString:@"26"] )
    {
        statusBack = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"Sunny"];
    }
    else
    {
        statusBack = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"Cloudy"];
    }

    return statusBack; //compile error
}


-(IBAction) customIBAction
{
  //call my custom function 
  //not sure how? 
  NSMutableString *str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"24"];
  NSString *returnedStr = my_func(str1); //compile error


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type from `void` to `NSString *`. BTW - this is a function, not a method. Any reason why?

```
NSString *my_func(NSString *string)
```

Comment: thank you. that was super fast. Will accept answer as soon as I am allowed to